# Write multi columns list on the fly

Tags: python, list, append, multiple-columns, finite-element-analysis

Hi i am writing a list as follow:

```
> l = [[10312, -13.069404602050781], [10313, -28.044403076171875],
>      [10314, -32.765602111816406], [10315, -47.353294372558594],
>      [10312, -63.069404602050781], [10313, -78.044403076171875],
>      [10314, -82.765602111816406], [10315, -97.353294372558594]]
```

as you can see from line 3 the first item of the list get repeated, what i am trying to achieve is that a soon as the loop reaches maxCount, instead of keep appending at the bottom of the list, it appends on the right. what i would ideally like to obtain is:

```
 l = [[10312, -13.069404602050781, -63.069404602050781], 
      [10313, -28.044403076171875, -78.044403076171875],
      [10314, -32.765602111816406, -82.765602111816406], 
      [10315, -47.353294372558594, -97.353294372558594]]
```

any ideas?

I have came up with a solution, but I feel a bit limited, I am using now a list of list generator, like this

```
 table=[]
     for k in range(0, len(elementContainer):
         k = []
         table.append(k)
```

I thought to you a dictionary generator but could not get it to work, any help or if you have a better solution.

Comment: dont know what this has to do with finite  elements, but it looks like python so i added that tag..

Comment: Thank you for the upvote and acceptance of my answer. I improved the code. Please, see my edit. I upvoted your interesting question, though the problem is very simple indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does the job, if I undesrtood correctly:

```
l = [[10312, -13.069404602050781], [10313, -28.044403076171875],
     [10314, -32.765602111816406], [10315, -47.353294372558594],
     [10312, -63.069404602050781], [10313, -78.044403076171875],
     [10314, -82.765602111816406], [10315, -97.353294372558594]]

from pprint import pprint
d = {}

for i,(x,n) in enumerate(l):
    print i,x,n
    if x in d:
        l[d[x]].append(n)
        del l[i][:]
    else:
        d[x] = i

l = filter(None,l)

pprint (l)
```

.

#### Edit

Here's a better algorithm because there's no more the filtering of the list done by the instruction `l = filter(None,l)` , so the transformation is in-place.

This instruction `l = filter(None,l)` creates a new list, that is to say a new object at another address in the memory: then the above code don't realize an in-place transformation of the list.
The following one performs such an in-place transformation, as it is put in evidence by the printing of the identities (id est addresses) of the list `l` before and after its treatment.

```
l = [[10312, -13.069404602050781],
     [10313, -28.044403076171875],
     [10314, -32.765602111816406],
     [10312, -63.069404602050781, -55.4444],
     [20666, -91, -92, -93, -94],
     [10315, -47.353294372558594],
     [10314, -82.765602111816406],
     [10315, -97.353294372558594],
     [10313, -78.044403076171875],
     [20666, -40.33, -94, -50.33, -91, -93]
     ]

from pprint import pprint
d = {}
to_del = []
print 'id(l) before : ',id(l)
pprint (l)

for i,subli in enumerate(l):
    if subli[0] in d:
        d[subli.pop(0)].extend(subli)
        to_del.insert(0,i)
    else:
        d[subli[0]] = subli

for i in to_del:
    del l[i]
    
print '\nid(l) after  : ',id(l)
pprint (l)
```

- Note that in the former code, the values of `d` were the indexes of the sublists of `l`.
  Now **in this new code, the values of `d` are directly the sublists of `l`**.
  It is more pythonic to reference objects directly, instead of referecing them indirectly through their indexes in the list whose they are elements of.
- The list `to_del` records the indexes of the sublists that will be deleted after the first loop. Each index added is inserted at the beginning of `to_del`  (not appended to it) so that the second loop ( `for i in to_del` )will **run retrogressively** through the list `l` , which **is the condition that must be respected when elements of a list are deleted on the basis of their indexes**.

The instruction `d[subli.pop(0)].extend(subli)` may seem somewhat a little  difficult to understand.

The operations begins with the execution of `subli.pop(0)` : this instruction triggers the extraction of the element indexed 0 from the sublist `subli` and returns it.
Then  `d[subli.pop(0)]` furnishes the object **subli.pop(0)** to `d` as a key, meanwhile this objects is removed from the sublist `subli`.
So, at this point, the sublist `subli` has been shortened of its first element, as if the instruction `subli[:] = subli[1:]` had been performed <sup>see remark at the bottom</sup>.

Next, the sublist `d[subli.pop(0)]` , that had been precedently encountered in `l` during the iteration through list `l` , is extended with the elements remaining in the sublist `subli` after this one has been shortened, that is to say with the elements that were indexed `1` to `len(subli)-1` BEFORE it was shortened.  But, as `subli` has been shortened, we only write `subli`, not `subli[1:]`.

And it works ! Result:

```
id(l) before :  18732936
[[10312, -13.069404602050781],
 [10313, -28.044403076171875],
 [10314, -32.765602111816406],
 [10312, -63.06940460205078, -55.4444],
 [20666, -91, -92, -93, -94],
 [10315, -47.353294372558594],
 [10314, -82.7656021118164],
 [10315, -97.3532943725586],
 [10313, -78.04440307617188],
 [20666, -40.33, -94, -50.33, -91, -93]]

id(l) after  :  18732936
[[10312, -13.069404602050781, -63.06940460205078, -55.4444],
 [10313, -28.044403076171875, -78.04440307617188],
 [10314, -32.765602111816406, -82.7656021118164],
 [20666, -91, -92, -93, -94, -40.33, -94, -50.33, -91, -93],
 [10315, -47.353294372558594, -97.3532943725586]]
```

.

If you want that only non-redudant elements be added to a previously existing sublist, it must be:

```
for i,subli in enumerate(l):
    print 1,subli
    if subli[0] in d:
        precsubli = d[subli.pop(0)]
        precsubli.extend(el for el in subli
                         if el not in precsubli)
        to_del.insert(0,i)
    else:
        d[subli[0]] = subli
```

.

#### Important remark

Note the difference :

```
N = [10000,2,3,4]

initial_id = id(N)
print initial_id, N

N = N[1:]

print id(N), N
print '%d==%d : %s' %\
      (initial_id, id(N), initial_id==id(N) )

print '------------------'

A = ['HEY','b','c','d']

initial_id = id(A)
print initial_id, A

A[:] = A[1:]

print id(A), A
print '%d==%d : %s' %\
      (initial_id, id(A), initial_id==id(A) )
```

result

```
18669480 [10000, 2, 3, 4]
11868480 [2, 3, 4]
18669480==11868480 : False
------------------
18731816 ['HEY', 'b', 'c', 'd']
18731816 ['b', 'c', 'd']
18731816==18731816 : True
```

That means that `A` is modified in-place, while object referenced by `N` is not: the instruction `N[1:]` builds a new object, at a location in the memory elsewhere than the location of the object referenced by `N`.

Comment: your first script eyquem works perfectly, considering that number of elem (1st colum) is of known length and all the other cols will carry the same len as col 1